# What's the difference between 'git fetch' and 'git fetch --all'

Tags: git, version-control, fetch, git-fetch

It seems to make no difference for the repo I'm working with, and the man page is not very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git fetch --all`  makes a difference if you have multiple remotes.  Most of the time you have only "origin", but you can add any number of remotes.

```
git clone ssh://example.com/git/repo/first-repo
git remote add my-other-remote ssh://example.com/git/repo/another
```

`git fetch` will fetch from "first-repo", where `git fetch --all` will fetch from "first-repo" and "another"